# Does anyone work with Function Points?

Tags: estimation, function-points

Some questions about Function Points:

1) Is it a reasonably precise way to do estimates?  (I'm not unreasonable here, but just want to know compared to other estimation methods)

2) And is the effort required worth the benefit you get out of it?

3) Which type of Function Points do you use?

4) Do you use any tools for doing this?

**Edit**: I am interested in hearing from people who use them or *have* used them.  I've read up on estimation practices, including pros/cons of various techniques, but I'm interested in the value in *practice*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mike Cohn in his [Agile Estimating and Planning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131479415) consider FPs to be great but difficult to get right. He (obviously) recommends to use story points-based estimation instead. I tend to agree with this as with each new project I see the benefits of Agile approach more and more.

---

*1) Is it a reasonably precise way to do estimates? (I'm not unreasonable here, but just want to know compared to other estimation methods)*

As far as estimation precision goes the functional points are very good. In my experience they are great but expensive in terms of effort involved if you want do it properly. Not that many projects could afford an elaboration phase to get the FP-based estimates right.

*2) And is the effort required worth the benefit you get out of it?*

FPs are great because they are officially recognised by ISO which gives your estimations a great deal of credibility. If you work on a big project for a big client it might be useful to invest in official-looking detailed estimations. But if the level of uncertainty is big to start with (like other vendors integration, legacy system, loose requirements etc.) you will not get anywhere near precision anyway so usually you have to just accept this and re-iterate the estimations later. If it is the case a cheaper way of doing the estimates (user stories and story points) are better.

*3) Which type of Function Points do you use?*

If I understand this part of your question correctly we used to do estimations based on the Feature Points but gradually moved away from these an almost all projects expect for the ones with heavy emphasis on the internal functionality.

*4) Do you use any tools for doing this?*

Excel is great with all the formulas you could use. Using Google Spreadsheets instead of Excel helps if you want to do that collaboratively.

There is also a great tool built-in to the [Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) Enterprise Architect which allows you to do the estimates based on the Use Cases which could be used for FP estimations as well.

Comment: Would you provide some links for good articles on story-based estimation? Thanks.

Comment: Frankly I think it's better to just read the man on them then to read anyone referring to his works. I would recommend getting the book - it's on pair with McConnell and other great must-have authors on SDP. You could get Cohn on Kindle from Amazon if you're interested in online

Answer (score 14):

I was an IFPUG Certified Function Point Specialist from 2002-2005, and I still use them to estimate business applications (web-based and thick-client). My experience is mostly with smaller projects (1000 FP or less).

I settled on Function Points after using Use Case Points and Lines of Code. (I've been actively working with estimation techniques for 10+ years now).

> Some questions about Function Points:
>
> 1) Is it a reasonably precise way to
>   do estimates? (I'm not unreasonable
>   here, but just want to know compared
>   to other estimation methods)

Hard to answer quickly, as it depends on where you are in the lifecycle (from gleam-in-the-eye to done). You also have to realize that there's more to estimation than precision.

Their greatest strength is that, when coupled with historical data, they hold up well under pressure from decision-makers. By separating the scope of the project from productivity (h/FP), they result in far more constructive conversations. (I first got involved in metrics-based estimation when I, a web programmer, had to convince a personal friend of my company's founder and CEO to go back to his investors and tell them that the date he had been promising was unattainable. We all knew it was, but it was the project history and functional sizing (home-grown use case points at the time) that actually convinced him.

Their advantage is greatest early in the lifecycle, when you have to assess the feasibility of a project before a team has even been assembled.

Contrary to common belief, it doesn't take that long to come up with a useful count, if you know what you're doing. Just off of the basic information types (logical files) inferred in an initial client meeting, and average productivity of our team, I could come up with a rough count (but no rougher than all the other unknowns at that stage) and a useful estimate in an afternoon.

Combine Function Point Analysis with a Facilitated Requirements Workshop and you have a great project set-up approach.

Once things were getting serious and we had nominated a team, we would then use Planning Poker and some other estimation techniques to come up with an independent number, and compare the two.

> 2) And is the effort required worth
>   the benefit you get out of it?

Absolutely. I've found preparing a count to be an excellent way to review user-goal-level requirements for consistency and completeness, in addition to all the other benefits. This was even in setting up Agile projects. I often found implied stories the customer had missed.

> 3) Which type of Function Points do
>   you use?

IFPUG CPM (Counting Practices Manual) 4.2

> 4) Do you use any tools for doing
>   this?

An Excel spreadsheet template I was given by the person who trained me. You put in the file or transaction attributes, and it does all of the table lookups for you.

As a concluding note, NO estimate is as precise (or more precisely, accurate) as the bean-counters would like, for reasons that have been well documented in many other places. So you have to run your projects in ways that can accommodate that (three cheers for Agile).

But estimates are still a vital part of decision support in a business environment, and I would never want to be without my function points. I suspect the people who characterize them as "fantasy" have never seen them properly used (and I have seen them overhyped and misused grotesquely, believe me).

Don't get me wrong, FP have an arbitrary feel to them at times. But, to paraphrase Churchill, Function Points are the worst possible early-lifecycle estimation technique known, except for all the others.

Comment: h/FP should be FP/h in the above post.  Productivity is "work done per unit of time" not "time per unit of work done".

Answer (score 6):

The great hacknot is offline now, but it is in book form.  He has an essay on function points: http://www.scribd.com/doc/459372/hacknot-book-a4, concluding they are a fantasy (which I agree with).

Joel on Software has a reasonable sound alternative called [Evidence based scheduling](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html) that at least **sounds** like it might work....

Answer (score 2):

From what I have study about Function Point (one of my teacher was highly involved in the process of the theory of function point) and he wasn't able to answer all our answers.Function point fail in many way because it's not because you have something read or write that you can evaluate correctly. You might have a result of 450 functions points and some of these function point will take 1 hour ans some will take 1 weeks. It's a metric that I will never use again.

Answer (score 1):

1. No because any particular requirement can have an arbitrary amount of effort based on how precise (or imprecise) the author of the requirement is, and the level of experience of the function point assessor.
2. No because administration of imprecise derivations of abstract functionality yield no reliable estimate.
3. None if I can help it.
4. Tools? For function points? How about Excel? Or Word? Or Notepad? Or Edlin?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes they are more precise than anything else I have encountered (in 20+ years).
2. Yes they are well worth the effort. You can estimate size, resources, quality and schedule from just the FP count - extremely useful.  It takes an average of 1 minute to count an FP manually and an average of 8 hours to fully code an FP (approximately $800 worth).  Consider the carpenter's saying of "measure twice cut once".  And now a shameless plug: with https://www.ScopeMaster.com you can measure 1 FP per second, and you don't need to learn how!
3. I like Cosmic Function Points (because they are versatile) and IFPUG because there is a lot of published data (mostly from Capers Jones).
4. Having invested considerable time, effort and money in developing a tool that counts FPs automatically from requirements,  I shall never have to do it manually again!

Comment: Any updates on that tool?