# Anyone used the ABC Metric for measuring an application's size?

Tags: metrics, measurement

There are some nice things about it (like it encapsulates the concept of Cyclomatic complexity), and I was wondering if anyone has used it in "real life".  If so, what are your experiences?  Is it a useful measure of size (as opposed to KLOC or Function Points)?

For those wondering what I'm smoking:
Here's a link to some info on it: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki/Wiki?AbcMetric

Comment: @torial: we don't do much FP nowdays but I've tried to reply as well as I could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118023/does-anyone-work-with-function-points#153458

Answer (score 2):

The application's sheer 'size' could be safely measured in LOCs or any other metrics you could think of as long as you use the same approach across all of your application.

However the size on its own really matters only when you're talking about re-factoring and maintainance of the code base. It's almost mandatory to use the size metrics are useful in conjuction with the coverage statistics.

But most of the time Function Points or similar concepts give you much better view of how big your application really is.

I.e. as an example if it has 10 FP it's tiny, if it has 200 it's probably big.

But if it has 100 KLOCs what does it tell me on its own, aside from the fact that I'll probably spend some time reading those lines? Almost nothing, I have to take an enourmous amount of other factors into an account to be able to understand this metric.

Obviously the FPs have a significant downside of being expensive to properly calculate.

Comment: Hi Ilya, do you by any chance use Function Points?  If so, I have another question, I'd appreciate you taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118023/does-anyone-work-with-function-points